# C++ efficient way to remove first x elements, push the x+1th element to the first without changing vector size

Tags: c++, vector

I'm wondering what's the most efficient(fastest, since the vector is not that big I don't care about memory usage) way to do this below:

Without changing vector size,
remove first x elements of the vector, push the rest of element to the first and assign new values to the last x elements. I guess vector::erase and ::push_back is probably not very fast since it change the size of the vector twice.

or is it better to give up vector and use arrays? Thanks.

Comment: So basically a [rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) or a [shift](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/shift) then replacing (overwriting) the last `x` elements?

Comment: If you care about efficiency, can you switch to `std::deque`? Otherwise, I won't be afraid of `erase` and `push_back`. Changing the vector size is not a problem, and the capacity is guaranteed to remain the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I think that's what I'm looking for, thanks

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica I still prefer the data to be contiguous in the memory so that's a no go. Thanks.

Comment: Efficent way to a small container doesn't make much sense for me...

Comment: @elvis.dukaj It's an audio buffer that's to be updated after every buffer update

Comment: If you are *really* concerned about efficiency and have PODs in the vector (e.g. int samples for audio) you can probably just `memmove`, first within the vector's data to shift the samples forward and then from the external data source into the end of vector's data for the new elements. The vector's size stays unaffected during the operation. Obviously the choice of vector then can be debated since you don't use the abstraction here, but it still offers a wrapper with convenient memory management and move semantics.

Comment: As @Peter-ReinstateMonica said, `memmove()` may be your best choice as it does not care about individual array elements. It just moves the bytes, and does so at the top speed your memory bus allows. You cannot get faster than the `memmove()` approach. Any native C++ vector operation would need to move the individual objects one by one, calling constructors and destructors along the way to ensure proper semantics, which can be significant overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vector::erase()` doesn't reallocate, it only moves contents within the already-allocated capacity and adjusts the size. (<s>Note that `erase()` doesn't throw `bad_alloc`, only copy/move/assignment exceptions.</s> EDIT: That's not really relevant to this scenario.)

So calling `erase()` should be no less efficient than calling `rotate()`.

`erase()` is probably more efficient, in fact, since `rotate()` not only moves the data that in your particular case you want to preserve, but also the data you're about to throw away - but which the semantics of `rotate()` dictate must also be preserved (which in turn probably necessitates either temporary storage or one-by-one movement).  You can hope the optimiser manages to deal with this, or you can call `erase()`.

Of course, the only real way to tell is to implement, measure, and compare.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your comment and as suggested by @Some programmer dude, this could do what you need:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    const size_t X = 3;
    std::rotate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + X, vec.end());
    std::transform(vec.end() - X, vec.end(), vec.end() - X, [](auto elem) {return elem += 10; });
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/823cb9248a8acad4)